# Using 'createSelector' - creating Custom 'useAppSelector' : Which approch is better?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, useselector

This is my code for cretaing Selectors

```
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from 'Store/InjectorsTypes';
import { initialState } from 'Slice/DocumentHubSlice';

const selectDomain = (state: RootState) => state?.documentHub || initialState;

export const selectDocuments = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.documents,
);

export const selectUploadedDocuments = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.uploadedDocuments,
);

export const selectDocumentsLoading = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.documentsLoading,
);

export const selectDocumentsLoaded = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.documentsLoaded,
);

export const selectDocumentsEnded = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.documentsEnded,
);

export const selectSort = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.sort,
);

export const selectCompanyName = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.companyName,
);

export const selectCompanyLogo = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.companyLogo,
);

export const selectChatGptAllowed = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.chatgptAllowed,
);

export const selectDrawerOpen = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.drawerOpen,
);

export const selectUploading = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.uploading,
);

export const selectDownloading = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.downloading,
);

export const selectDeleting = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.deleteing,
);

export const selectDownloadUrl = createSelector(
  [selectDomain],
  (state) => state.downloadUrl,
);
```

However, I can see too much redundancy. I want to replace above code with my this code

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { RootState } from 'Store/InjectorsTypes';
import { initialState } from 'Slice/DocumentHubSlice';

export function useAppSelector<T>(selector: (state: RootState) => T) {
  return useSelector((state: RootState) => selector(state) || initialState);
}
```

With this custom hook, I can use it in my components like this

```
const documents = useAppSelector((state) => state.documentHub.documents);
const uploadedDocuments = useAppSelector((state) => state.documentHub.uploadedDocuments);
// ... and so on
```

I want to know if the second approach is better than the first. Should I replace my initial code with this second appraoch?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should always be using the `useAppSelector` shown in [the "TypeScript quickstart" guide for Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#use-typed-hooks-in-components), independenlty of the question if you use `createSelector` or not.

Apart from that, you probably don't *need* `createSelector` for any of the examples you've given, as long as those selectors don't do any meaningful (expensive) calculation or create new objects - in those two cases, you should always use memoized selectors.

But it doesn't hurt to use them either - so it's up to you.

PS: That `|| initialState` is seriously weird - you'll always have a state there, so why add that?